# Google Maps API formatted_address

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I am using php to convert latitude and longitude to an address in a WordPress custom field. It works how I want except I get the country at the end of the address (ex. 1234 1st st City State 90210 USA).

This is the code I'm using to make the conversion. Any thoughts on how to remove the country name?

```
function getaddress($post_id)
{
  $coorloc = get_field('event_location');

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.urlencode($coorloc).'&sensor=false';
$json = @file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json);
$status = $data->status;
if($status=="OK")
$address = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
update_post_meta($post_id, "geocoderaddress", $address);

}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'getaddress', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to as google provides `address_components` for this very reason.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&latlng=51.278777,-0.951090

The API provides each component so you can use each part however you want.

`address_components` snippet for reference:

```
{
   "long_name":"United Kingdom",
   "short_name":"GB",
   "types":[
      "country",
      "political"
   ]
},
{
   "long_name":"RG27 9XB",
   "short_name":"RG27 9XB",
   "types":[
      "postal_code"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea

```
$addressBits = explode(" ", $address);
$parts = count($addressBits);
for($i = o; $i <= $parts - 1; $i++){
    $newAddress .= $addressBits[$i] . " "; 
}
```

maybe you could try something like this